# Command Line Output of .jar is Different than its Output When Run by C# Code

Tags: java, c#, mono, html-agility-pack, htmlunit

I have a .jar file named "DynamicContentLoader.jar" that executes a Java process that connects to a web page, using HtmlUnit, and prints its Html document via  `System.out.println();`. This Process takes one argument from the command line: the URI of the webpage needed to be retrieved.

Code of the Java process thats exported to the .jar file:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class DynamicContentLoader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    String s = DynamicContentLoader.loadHtml("https://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&contentCollection&region=TopBar&WT.nav=searchWidget&module=SearchSubmit&pgtype=Homepage#/Donald%20Trump");

    System.out.println(s);
}

public static String loadHtml(String url) {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false); //if you don't need css
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); // stop process breaking exception throws

    HtmlPage page;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20 * 1000); /* will wait JavaScript to execute up to 5s */

        String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
        webClient.close();

        return pageAsXml;
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Next, I execute this .jar within a Mono project with a class that uses a `Process` Object to execute the .jar, read its `StandardOutput` stream into a `StringBuilder`, then create and return an `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` object from `StringBuilder.ToString();`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Search {
    public static class DynamicContentLoader {
        // path of .jar file in ProjectDirectory/Resources/.jar
        readonly static string jarPath = 
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + 
            "Resources/DynamicContentLoader.jar";

        public static HtmlDocument LoadDynamicWebPage(string url) {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", @" -jar " 
                 + jarPath + " \'" + url + "\'");

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            var javaProcess = new Process();
            javaProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;  
            javaProcess.Start();  

            var output = new StringBuilder();
            while (!javaProcess.HasExited) {
                output.Append(javaProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }

            if (output.Length > 0) {
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(output.ToString());

                // looking see if correct Html doc
                Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);

                return doc;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I run the .jar from the command line,

"java -jar path/to/file/DynamicContentLoader.jar 'some uri'"

I get the correctly loaded Html doc/string. However, my C# code above returns a different, incomplete Html doc/string, or even crashes with exceptions like:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
atorg.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
     Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: 
     Cannot find function all in object function Promise() { [native code] }
```

Does anyone know what may cause the difference in behavior between these two different execution methods or what will fix this issue?

Comment: Can you share the entry method or your jar file?

Comment: You aren't using the shell execute, the execution environment is not the same as if it were launched on the command line. I can't extensively explain this as I know nothing more than one uses Explorer to run the process and other is started by the Kernel itself, but I should assume there is some environment difference which makes it to fail.

Comment: @MattClark sure thing, just updated the post with this info

Comment: @Gusman Is there a way to set up my .NET project so that the execution environments will be similar? I'm using Xamarin Studio on OSX if that helps at all

Comment: First I would check if this is the problem, launch the process from .net without redirecting the output and using shell execute, if it works then you need to find the environment difference, I think it may be the environment variables, like JAVA_HOME

Comment: Waitwaitwait, Mono on MacOS? That's totally different, I can't ensure anything there as the execution is totally different to Windows. Anyway try what I recommended on the previous comment. ANd also, add to your question a clarification you're using Mono on MacOS X, it's very different to .net on Windows when it regards to low level functions like the ones manipulating processes.

Comment: @Gusman Ok thanks I'll check that out and update my post

Comment: @Gusman looking into your suggestion, the .jar is executing in with my C# code, but the output is not the same/wrong compared to running it from the command line (and some cases its throwing Java exceptions, the ones mentioned above). I can't use `SetShellExecute = true` because I need the output and even testing it with setting that to true doesn't help because I can't see if its acting properly

Comment: You will see the output in a new console, when you use shellexecute it will run in a sepparate window and you can check if the output is correct.

Comment: @Gusman ah I see. I just ran it that way and the same issues persist. The output from the .jar is still different when executed from the command line compared to the C# code